# How to force IntelliJ IDEA to convert all java files from spaces to tabs?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an existing project, where some of the java files have tabs, some have spaces for indentation.
I want to make ALL java files based on tabs, but there are hundreds of them, the action of "to tabs" is not realistic I am not going to go manually over multiple modules, hundreds of files!

Is there any other way to do it smartly without going through individual files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps to follow.

- Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java
- Tabs and Indents > Click [Use tab character]
- Go to `tree structure`/`Project window` (the main side tab of project hierarchy display)
- Right click the folder(or project) you want to convert and select `Reformat code` & `Run`

Comment: this did not work for me, old files stayed with spaces indents instead of tabs